# How to convert all .xls to .xlsx in a folder recursively using Powershell without Excel installed

Tags: excel, powershell

Is there a way to convert all .xls to .xlsx in a folder recursively without Excel being installed using Powershell?

Comment: No, but you can do this with Excel installed without Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need Excel, but it doesn't have to be on the same machine. If you can share this folder on a network, you can run your script from any machine where Excel is installed and also has write access to the shared folder.

Failing that, PowerShell has the ability to use any .Net assembly, and there are third-party (non-Microsoft) *paid* .Net libraries for working with Excel. The trick is these typically cost more than an Excel license, are just as painful to install, and the third-party nature means you're rolling the dice on the actual conversion quality.

Comment: As an aside to the question, I'd really love to see MS release a fully-first-party and _supported_ GUI-less set of APIs for working with Office documents. They could even license it for Windows server editions only.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft provides the [OMPM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11454) (Office Migration Planning Manager), which includes a little tool called ofc.exe

You can configure this tool to convert all files (recursive) in a directory to the new format, without Excel being installed, you can even specify if macros should be included or not.

The only installation prerequisite is the Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack.